# How to modify panels in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, 10.04, 13.04, gnome-classic

**English version**:
I've installed Gnome on my Ubuntu 13.04, since I prefer it over Unity.

Unlike 10.04, I can't right-click the upper and lower panels, and I can't find a way to remove the upper panel so the menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) floats as in my old Ubuntu.

I would also like to add quick access icons to the lower panel, which I could do in 10.04 simply by right-clicking and selecting "Add to panel".

---

**Original text**:
 necesito ayuda con Ubuntu 13.04.
Despues de instalar mi ubuntu 13.04 instale el GNOME porque es el que siempre use en mi vieja PC cuando tenía Ubuntu 10.04 y lo prefiero mucho más que Unity. Pero luego de instalarlo a diferencia de mi anterior Ubuntu no puedo darle click derecho a los paneles superior e inferior. Por lo que no se como quitar el de arriba, así consigo que el menú (Alt+F1) sea flotante como en mi viejo Ubuntu. 
También quiero agregar accesos al panel de abajo, que en 10.04 se hacía con solo darle click derecho y luego: "agregar al panel".

Estaría muy agradecido si me ayudan.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a AskUbuntu! Este sitio está en inglés, por lo que sería bueno que hagás el intento de usar ese idioma; de otro modo corrés el riesgo de que tu pregunta sea cerrada o quede sin respuestas adecuadas. Si tenés problemas con el inglés, escribí tu pregunta en español y una traducción robótica de servicios tales como el de [translate.ru](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=es) o el de Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No estoy seguro con el 13.04, pero con el 12.04 tienes que darle a Alt + Super(el boton con la icona de windows) + boton derecho
- Not sure with Ubuntu 13.04, but with Ubuntu 12.04 you have to click Alt+Super(the button with the windows icon) + right button

Comment: Please provide the answer in English (along with the Spanish-language for the benefit of @Gonzalo).